# Trying to publish Lightning Message Channel from Visualforce page and getting error `Sfdc is not defined`

Tags: visualforce, lightning-message-service

I am trying to publish a message from a visualforce page into a lightning component and my visualforce page is not able to publish.

My Visualforce code :

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" lightningStylesheets="true">
<html>
<head>
  <apex:includeScript value="/sforce/one/49.0/api.js"></apex:includeScript>
  <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/49.0/connection.js"></apex:includeScript>
  <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/49.0/apex.js"></apex:includeScript>
  <apex:slds />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slds-scope">
    <button class="slds-button" onclick="publishMC()">Publish</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    const SAMPLEMC = "{!$MessageChannel.MySampleChannel__c}";
    function publishMC() {
      const payload = {
        recordId: "hello",
        recordData: { value: "world" },
      };
      sforce.one.publish(SAMPLEMC, payload);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

But When I'm running this visualforce page I'm getting this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sfdc is not defined        --- api.js:237

When Clicking the button I'm getting this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'publish' of undefined

What am I am I'm missing here to get the publish lightning message channel working from Visualforce page ?

Thanks